# I used single quote to design HTML of my WordPress blog. Now site redirects to index.php everytime than page.php or single.php

Tags: theme-development, redirect, htaccess, html, 404-error

I am actually building a custom theme for my blog and I use single quotes for HTML everywhere like:

```
<div class='div'></div>
```

Does this cause me redirection to index.php??

My site correctly redirects at 301, mod_rewrite is enabled and responses to links but open index.php. Is this because I used single quote??

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. Single quotes can't cause redirects.

Comment: Not even if they try, like really, really hard?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is perfectly fine to use single quotation in HTML, and it has nothing to do with the problems you are experiencing.

Have you tried to refresh permalinks in the Dashboard? Check this out: [Flushing Permalinks in WordPress](https://typerocket.com/flushing-permalinks-in-wordpress/).